# Connection attempt failed MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm failing to connect to a mysql database (running in a docker container) even after trying several methods!

**Note:** This [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731674/connection-attempt-failed-mysql-poco) does not solve my issue because I tried it.

Here is the code for my connection in C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <Poco/Data/MySQL/MySQLException.h>
#include <Poco/Data/MySQL/Connector.h>
#include <Poco/Data/SessionFactory.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector();
    try
    {
        string str = "host=0.0.0.0;port=3306;user=admin;db=myServiceDb;password=password;compress=true;auto-reconnect=true";
        Poco::Data::Session test(Poco::Data::SessionFactory::instance().create(Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::KEY, str));
    }
    catch (Poco::Data::ConnectionFailedException &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the docker compose code

```
services:
  myServiceDb:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ' myServiceDb'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'rootpassword'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
```

I have tried to change the host name from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1` but all fails. I have also tried to connect using Python but it also failed.

Surprisingly, I'm able to connect the db using MySQLWorkbench with the same credentials so I think the problem is in MySQL itself.

For reference, I'm using a Mac with MacOS 12.6.

What should I change to have a successful connection?

Comment: Is this C++ also in a container? You say "It fails", but what errors do you receive from this code when it can't connect? It seems very unlikely that the issue is with mysql BECAUSE you can connect with mysqlworkbench. When you connect with mysqlworkbench, what are you connection settings? Do they match what you are using in this code?

Comment: The full Error message in C++ is `libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type Poco::Data::ConnectionFailedException: Connection attempt failed`. 
Yes, I can connect with the same credentials in MySQLWorkbench.

Answer (score 0):

As you can evidently see, My error originated from the space in the `MYSQL_DATABASE` field in the `docker-compose`.

I fixed it by changing `' myServiceDb'` to `'myServiceDb'`.

Thanks for your help. I feel like a clown right now!